# Can someone explain to me Nozick's argument against epistemic closure?

Tags: metaphysics, nozick

> On the other hand, some epistemologists, including Robert Nozick, have
> denied closure principles on the basis of reliabilist accounts of
> knowledge. Nozick, in Philosophical Explanations, advocated that, when
> considering the Gettier problem, the least counter-intuitive
> assumption we give up should be epistemic closure. Nozick suggested a
> "truth tracking" theory of knowledge, in which the x was said to know
> P if x's belief in P tracked the truth of P through the relevant modal
> scenarios.[2]

I chanced upon this article not too long ago, and I was wondering what was meant here. What is meant by reliabilist accounts of knowledge? And how does it work against such basic idea that if we know q and q entails x, then we know x, which should be basic common sense derived from logic?

Comment: This page is your friend: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/closure-epistemic/

Comment: Nozick explains it himself in [Philosophical Explanations (free link), p. 206ff](https://antilogicalism.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/philosophical-explanations.pdf). Roughly, on his definition knowledge, in addition to being true belief, must satisfy the"sensitivity" condition:"*if p were false, S wouldn't believe that p*", and it is not preserved by implication. That I am sitting in a chair implies that I am not a brain in a vat, but the former is counterfactually sensitive while the latter is not. So I may know that I am in a chair *without* knowing that I am not a brain in a vat.